# Is it possible to get an intersection type of Record from keys and values as tuples or unions that is one-to-one?

Tags: typescript

Given the following tuples: (as an example. I could swap to string unions if that would make it possible.)

```
type Keys = ['North', 'East', 'South', 'West'];
type Values = ['n', 'e', 's', 'w'];
```

How can I get something similar to this:

```
type OneToOne<
  K extends [...(string | number | symbol)[]],
  V extends [...unknown[]]
> = Record<K[0], V[0]>
  & Record<K[1], V[1]>
  & Record<K[2], V[2]>
  & Record<K[3], V[3]>;
```

But for any arbitrarily long tuples and or unions. Whether `K` and `V` are tuples or string unions in the end, doesn't make that much of a difference to me. I suppose they would just need to be the same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mapped type to iterate over the keys of `Keys`, filtering out only number keys ("0", "1", etc). Then you can use this number key to index into `Keys` for the property type (in the `as` clause of the mapped type) and get the corresponding value out of `Values`:

```
type Keys = ['North', 'East', 'South', 'West'];
type Values = ['n', 'e', 's', 'w'];

type KetValues<K extends PropertyKey[], V extends Record<keyof K & number, string>> = {
  [P in keyof K as P extends `${number}` ? K[P] & PropertyKey : never]: V extends Record<P, infer Prop> ? Prop: never
}

type x = KetValues<Keys, Values>
// type x = {
//     North: "n";
//     East: "e";
//     South: "s";
//     West: "w";
// }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=5&pln=12&pc=19#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcoF4oG0DkA5A9gJ2AAsMAaKDAUQEMFhTyBlHAVyPowHUJaMBdAbgBQoSFABqVADbNuKdBgB27COwTsA7nyHDw0OMAnTuAHhhQIAD2AQFAEyQAFPDkgEQcEGl5kx5qzfsoACUIAGN8W2MAa3gcADNYKAAyKAVmAFsAIwg8Mlo8AEsFAHMAPlK5AG9BKHQHKCKoGJB4xJooestrOyQAAwASSrSsnIBfXqgAflg0B15kjudXUA8oAC5UiAA3HN4N3y6ApBDwvEiHMiK4nMWXCumnFw2FbZzBUcEdUQs5fUMZBCmeAIHxSAGlQQAekhUBE0B+qGq0NqKNwBEIGwARApMUJkSioNRaFiILioTCCUxWBioJiEGT8SiuMTaeoGTDRkA)